# Use python to open browser and click, using only built-in modules

Tags: python, controller, click

I need to use python to open a browser window, open a specific URL, and click on one specific element.

I don't want to use Selenium, Mechanize, or other such tools, because I want others to be able to use my script without having to download these extra modules.

Is there a way to accomplish this using the built-in modules?

Thanks

Edit: I tried using webbrowser and realized, as falstru mentioned, that it can't do much beyond open the URL. I think what I will do is use Selenium and figure out how to use virtualenv to make Selenium available to users.

Comment: & what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, it is not possible only with standard library.

Using [`webbrowser.open`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html), you can open the url, but you can't control the browser with the module.